# Build a simple ticker that change the divs every 6 seconds using animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I'm doing something wrong here with this simple task:
I have 2 divs, both have id's, i want one to replace the other every 6 seconds, that's it (with animate css animations, enter and leave).
This is my html:

```
 <div class="mood-area" style="position:relative">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute" id="tickBox1">
           First div
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;display:none" id="tickBox2">
            <div class="flex-all flex-center" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                Some other Div
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And im doing this in interval every 6 seconds: (angular interval)

```
 $interval(function(){
            //check which is the one with the display none, this should be the one that enters and the other one goes out
            var element         = null;
            var elementToReturn = null;
            if($('#tickBox2').css('display') == 'none')
            {
                element         = $('#tickBox1');

                elementToReturn = $('#tickBox2');

            } else {
                element         = $('#tickBox2');

                elementToReturn = $('#tickBox1');

            }
            element.addClass('animated slideOutDown');
            element.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                elementToReturn.addClass('animated slideInDown');
                elementToReturn.css("display", "block");
                element.css("display", "none");
                element.removeClass("animated slideInDown");
            });
        },6000);
```

The first iteration is good, the second one starts to jump and goes crazy, what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because You are not removing classes from `elementToReturn`, add to Your function:

```
elementToReturn.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
    elementToReturn.removeClass('animated slideInDown slideOutDown');
});
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xevwt2ex/)

Comment: It worked, is there a better and more professional way to write this thing?

Comment: My code would look something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xevwt2ex/1/). Dont limit Yourself to two slides and I would use some separate classes in JS that not appears in CSS. for example with prefix js-* or __*

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I changed from 6 to 2 seconds for convenience.
http://jsfiddle.net/59698L32/

```
$("#start").on("click", function(){
   change();

});

function change(){
 setTimeout(function(){
    $(".content").slideToggle(2000);
     change();
 }, 2000);

}
```

and html:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="content" id="first">

        </div>   
        <div class="content hide" id="second">

        </div>  

    </div>

    <a href="#" id="start">START</a>

<body>
```